# Изменение цвета при нажатии на кнопку со своим стилем

Tags: java, android, button, android-layout

Мне нужно при нажатии на кнопку, менять ее цвет, но при этом моя кнопка имеет закругленные углы, то есть уже имеется файл xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
   <corners android:radius="4dp" />
   <solid android:color="@color/colorTitle" />
</shape>
```

Чтобы поменять цвет кнопки при нажатии необходим еще 1 xml файл, так как там присутствует root tag `<selector>`, понятное дело, что можно сделать картинку с закругленными углами, но есть ли другой вариант? спасибо.

Comment: Аналоги xml файлов можно создать программно

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В файле стиля для кнопки Вы можете задать оформление виджета для различных состояний:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:shape="rectangle">
                <corners android:radius="4dp"/>
                <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item>
        <shape
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:shape="rectangle">
                <corners android:radius="4dp"/>
                <solid android:color="@color/colorAccent"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Здесь в pressed-состоянии кнопка будет иметь цвет `@color/colorPrimary`, а в default-состоянии – `@color/colorAccent`.

Comment: да работает, благодарю)